# HIde node in view when field message is equal

Tags: views, 7, nodes

Can I hide a node in a view when they have a specific message? Like, if the message: "Please don't show this node" is equal with specific field content then hide him in the view, else show him?

Is there an option for this?

Comment: No I don't think you'll find an option for that. What do you mean by 'message' exactly?

Comment: I have jQuery countdown now, if this is ended, there is an message. This shows "You are to late". This works all, but I created a view also and this take al the nodes from a content type. What I want is that the node is not showing up in this view when the jQuery countdown is ended. But I have no idea how.

Comment: Ok...what method are you using to populate the field in the backend when the jQuery countdown finishes? AJAX I would guess, but is it part of the jQyery countdown module or have you implemented it yourself?

Comment: It is an Auction module with a jQuery countdown. When the auction ended hide the node in the view.

Comment: If the countdown is based on the start / end date of the auction, you should be able to have the View filter on auctions that are only happening between those dates.

Comment: Could you tell me how?

Answer (score 1):

Just an idea if you can try...

As per my point of view you may try to use flags with the timer? whenever the countdown is ended invoke a flag and you can use this flag in views.If the flag is invoked do not show the content else it will be visible.